# What does mean futex_?

Tags: c, linux, mutex

My appliction all of a sudden, stops working. and i executed following comand,

```
#ps -elf  | grep aeroServ
```

and Got the following output,

```
#0 S binunun   5634  2300  0  80   0 -  7781 futex_ 15:41 pts/0    00:00:04
```

What i could able to sense is that, application is not running, but i do not understand which state the process is now. Could someone kindly explain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's the `WCHAN` column of the `ps` output.

As the man page says:

> `nwchan`     `WCHAN`   address of the kernel function where the process is sleeping (use wchan if you want the kernel function name). Running tasks will display a dash ('-') in this column.

So your process is blocked on a `futex_*` call in kernel (these calls are related to mutex locking/unlocking and other synchronization primitives). *Why* it's blocked there, only you can tell by inspecting your code and/or using a debugger.

(See [Futex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futex) for information on futexes.)

Comment: Simple and superb explanation.